# How to move the last array into the div

Tags: javascript, html

I created a navigation menu with dropdown and multi menu functions and there were some problems that occurred. I tried to improve one by one and it worked, but now I am confused about how this one is. maybe I get the answer here.

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.LinkList ul li a'),
  getDropdown = dropdown.length;
for (var i = 0; i < getDropdown - 1; i++) {
  var menu = dropdown[i],
    menutext = menu.textContent;
  if (menutext.charAt(0) !== "_") {
    var submenu = dropdown[i + 1],
      submenutext = submenu.textContent;
    if (submenutext.charAt(0) === '_') {
      menu.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', '<ul class="sub-menu m-sub"/>')
    }
  }
  if (menutext.charAt(0) === '_') {
    menu.textContent = menutext.replace('_', '')
    document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu').forEach(el => {
      el.appendChild(menu.parentElement)
    })
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < getDropdown - 1; i++) {
  var menu2 = dropdown[i],
    menutext2 = menu2.textContent;
  if (menutext2.charAt(0) !== '_') {
    var submenu2 = dropdown[i + 1],
      submenutext2 = submenu2.textContent;
    if (submenutext2.charAt(0) === '_') {
      menu2.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', '<ul class="sub-menu2 m-sub"/>')
    }
  }
  if (menutext2.charAt(0) === '_') {
    menu2.textContent = menutext2.replace('_', '')
    document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu2').forEach(el => {
      el.appendChild(menu2.parentElement)
    })
  }
}
document.querySelectorAll('.LinkList ul li ul').forEach(el => {
  el.parentElement.classList.add('has-sub')
})
```

```html
<div class='main-nav'>
  <div class='LinkList'>
    <ul role='menubar'>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>Submenu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Multimenu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>Submenu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Multimenu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Menu</a></li>
      <!-- if I add a regular menu, the menu with the text _menu will be moved -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

if I add a regular menu, the menu with the text `_menu` will be moved, I want it without the need for a regular menu again then _menu will be moved to parrentElement automatically

Comment: Please use meaningful variable names, not all these 1-letter variables. This looks like minified code.

Comment: I'm just confused to name it, but I re-edit this post.

Comment: I have re-edited the variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last li is not recognized since your for loops run for one time to less because of subtracting 1 from the number of li's `i < getDropdown - 1`. Remove at both for loops the subtraction `i < getDropdown`.

Since you get in every for loop the next element with `i + 1` ("*submenu*" or "*submenu2*") you have an error for the last element (the code works although). To get rid of the error you can use a ternary operator `?` (could also be an if statement) to check if the element exists `submenutext = submenu ? submenu.textContent : '';`

**Working example**:

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.LinkList ul li a'),
getDropdown = dropdown.length;
for (var i = 0; i < getDropdown; i++) {
  var menu = dropdown[i],
  menutext = menu.textContent;
  if (menutext.charAt(0) !== "_") {
    var submenu = dropdown[i + 1],
    submenutext = submenu ? submenu.textContent : '';
    if (submenutext.charAt(0) === '_') {
      menu.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', '<ul class="sub-menu m-sub"/>')
    }
  }
  if (menutext.charAt(0) === '_') {
    menu.textContent = menutext.replace('_', '')
    document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu').forEach(el => {
      el.appendChild(menu.parentElement)
    })
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < getDropdown; i++) {
  var menu2 = dropdown[i],
  menutext2 = menu2.textContent;
  if (menutext2.charAt(0) !== '_') {
    var submenu2 = dropdown[i + 1],
    submenutext2 = submenu2 ? submenu2.textContent : '';
    if (submenutext2.charAt(0) === '_') {
      menu2.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', '<ul class="sub-menu2 m-sub"/>')
    }
  }
  if (menutext2.charAt(0) === '_') {
    menu2.textContent = menutext2.replace('_', '')
    document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu2').forEach(el => {
      el.appendChild(menu2.parentElement)
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='main-nav'>
  <div class='LinkList'>
    <ul role='menubar'>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>Submenu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Multimenu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>Submenu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Multimenu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>__Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' role='menuitem'>_Menu</a></li>
      <!-- if I add a regular menu, the menu with the text _menu will be moved -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but when I add the regular menu without the `_` below it will get an error

Comment: I understand now, it turns out that we can manipulate extras with both ternary and binary operators, I am very grateful, for the answer and very helpful